# How to find Pauli matrices

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I wanted to find the Pauli matrices, so I wrote down this code:

```
z = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
i = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
Solve[z.z == i, {a, b, c, d}]
```

and *Mathematica* gave me this:

> {{c -> (1 - a^2)/b, d -> -a}, {a -> -1, b -> 0, d -> 1}, {a -> 1, 
>     b -> 0, d -> -1}, {a -> -1, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> -1}, {a -> -1, 
>     b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 1}, {a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> -1}, {a -> 1,
>      b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 1}}

Where are the complex solutions?

Comment: These solutions contain free parameters, which can be complex. I hope you know the built-in function `PauliMatrix`.

Comment: Yes, I know the function PauliMatrix, but i asked me how to obtain all the solutions for a b c and d

Comment: Ok I understand, so what conditions should I add to obtain Pauli Matrices?

Comment: What complex solutions are you looking for? Observe that `Solve[z.z == -i, {a, b, c, d}]` gives the expected complex values.